# Reset entity id - Spring Boot Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have a simple application for a bookstore and I would like to reset the generated id after the client does a `deleteAll` operation.

This is the entity for a `Book`:

```kotlin
@Entity
class Book(@Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long, @NotNull var name: String)
```

The `BookController` and the `deleteAll` method:

```kotlin
@RestController
class BookController(val repo: BookRepository) {

@DeleteMapping("/deleteall")
    fun deleteAllBooks() {
        repo.deleteAll()
    }
}
```

I'm using an H2 database since it's only used for learning purposes. The main issue is that after sending a delete request and then posting another book, the latter does have an incremented id from the last book added instead of having the counter reset and starting from 1.

Comment: Why you would need to reuse IDs at all?

Comment: Please provide an info on why exactly your are trying to reset the index. This is not a good practice in general